# I need to have a subnets on my domain route to 3 different vms im running on my network

Tags: apache-virtualhost, nextcloud

Let me start by mentioning that I'm a programmer that has been learning the magical world of networking. I'm not going to begin to believe that all if any of my design decisions have been entirely correct but I have a decent grasp on networking fundamentals and Linux. I have my main VM hosting a webpage on port :443 for traffic to my site and my nextcloud instance https://my_domain.com/nextcloud. It's signed using certbot and is working great. What I need is to have:'

https://webmin.my_domain.com  --> goto --> port :10000 of internal IP 192.168.1.XXX
https://minio.my_domain.com --> goto --> port :9000 of internal IP 192.168.1.XXX
https://cloud.tiptonit.com --> goto ---> some port on the same internal IP of the my primary website.

I know the answer lies somewhere in virtual hosts but I haven't been able to get anything to work after much google searching and long nights with coffee. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

(also my domain is hosted with Google Domains)

Thanks guys,
-Caleb (a humble programmer)

Answer (score 0):

Look up how to set up reverse proxies. What you want to do is pretty much the same, but serving from localhost instead of a different machine.